# Next button opens another activity when its reaches the array limit

Tags: java, android

I am developing a quiz application with two navigation buttons (back and next), and each quiz has an array of 30 questions. Now when btnnext reaches the last question, it should open another activity(Review) when u click on it again

```
next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
        next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        next.setOnClickListener(nextListener);

private View.OnClickListener nextListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setAnswer();
        quesIndex++;
        if (quesIndex >= QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length())
            quesIndex = QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length() - 1;
        showQuestion(quesIndex,review);
    }
};
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting and what actually you want?
If you want an activity to open use intent and start activity in onClick

Comment: with the above code showed, there is no error, its does nothing when it reaches the last question but what i want is that, when it reaches the last question, the button text should change to Finish and when you click on it it takes you to a review page (another activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
        next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        next.setOnClickListener(nextListener);

private View.OnClickListener nextListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setAnswer();
        if (quesIndex != QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()-1) {
            quesIndex++;
            showQuestion(quesIndex,review);
        }
        else {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
            CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
        if (quesIndex == QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()-1)
            next.setText("Finish");
    }
};
```

Comment: this works but does not start the intent when it gets to the finish.....any reasons why?

Comment: there is no reason I can catch. it must work. double check the code you use to launch new activity.

Answer (score 0):

Add the piece of code for next activity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

You have to check for the last question and change the button view text to finish.